# Fading in appended elements one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with IDs and I am loading elements with these IDs from another page.

```
    $.each(idArr, function() {
        var divline = '<div class="line" id="' + this + '">';
        var url = 'allitems.php #' + this + ' div';
        $('#the-list').append($(divline).load(url).hide().fadeIn());
    });
```

It works fine but I would like the loaded elements to fade in one at a time, or at least not all att once. I cannot figure out how to use .delay with my code. Or is there maybe another way?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(idArr, function(i,el) {
    var divline =  $('<div />', {'class':'line', id: el}),
        url = 'allitems.php #' + el + ' div';
    $('#the-list').append(divline.load(url).hide().delay(i*1000).fadeIn());
});
```

Comment: And another +1 (this one looks like the best to me)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use `setTimeout` :

```
$.each(idArr, function(i) {
    var divline = '<div class="line" id="' + this + '">';
    var url = 'allitems.php #' + this + ' div';
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#the-list').append($(divline).load(url).hide().fadeIn());
    }, i*1000);
});
```

Comment: Damnit I was just about to hit "Post your Answer" with the same solution haha. +1 ol' chap!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$(".elements").each(function(i, e) { $(e).delay(i * 400).fadeIn(400); });
```

Comment: In the end, it'll do the same !